# Monoid algebra in GAP

Tags: representation-theory, gap

Given a monoid in GAP, for example

```
G:=FullTransformationSemigroup(3);
<full transformation monoid of degree 3>
```

> Question: Can one build the monoid algebra of G over a field using GAP? Im just aware of this for groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monoid algebras are examples of magma rings:

```
gap> G:=FullTransformationSemigroup(3);
<full transformation monoid of degree 3>
gap> FG:=FreeMagmaRing(GF(3),G);
<algebra-with-one over GF(3), with 3 generators>
```

Zero and one:

```
gap> z:=Zero(FG);
<zero> of ...
gap> e:=One(FG);
(Z(3)^0)*IdentityTransformation
```

Canonical embedding:

```
gap> emb:=Embedding(G,FG);
<mapping: Monoid( [ Transformation( [ 2, 3, 1 ] ), Transformation( [ 2, 1 ] ), 
  Transformation( [ 1, 2, 1 ] ) ] ) -> AlgebraWithOne( GF(3), ... ) >
```

Some manipulations with elements:

```
gap> a:=Random(G);
Transformation( [ 3, 2, 1 ] )
gap> b:=Random(G);
Transformation( [ 3, 3, 3 ] )
gap> x:=a^emb;
(Z(3)^0)*Transformation( [ 3, 2, 1 ] )
gap> y:=b^emb;
(Z(3)^0)*Transformation( [ 3, 3, 3 ] )
gap> x+y+x*y;
(Z(3)^0)*Transformation( [ 3, 2, 1 ] )+(Z(3))*Transformation( [ 3, 3, 3 ] )
```

For further details, please see the GAP manual [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap65.html).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get the blocks of a monoid algebra in gap? For example the blocks of the algebra FG in your example.

Comment: Could you point to the blocks definition please?

Comment: A block is an indecomposable algebra $B_i$ such that the original algebra $FG$ is the product of the algebras $B_i$ (just like for group algebras in modular representation theory). For $n \geq 5$ over the rational numbers the monoid algebra of the full transformation monoid has two blocks. One block is simple and not interesting, so it would be nice to somehow get only the interesting block.

Comment: The question was about creating a monoid algebra, and was answered. Followup questions should be questions on their own and not fill up discussion.