# Is there a CAS that by default handles monoid rings?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-software, computer-algebra-systems

I'm aware that sage has monoid features, but not necc. monoid ring.

Is there a CAS specializing in: rings, groups, modules, monoid rings, group rings?

Reason, is that these structures are hard to work with and if I could give examples as CAS presentations, that would be ideal.

Alternatively, a proof assistant that supports these is okay too.

Comment: Yes - [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org), please see [GAP manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap65.html) and questions like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444110/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256497/. There are also several packages for group rings at https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/packages.html